# jQuery one fires more than once if there are more than one elements in the $ selector, how to make it only fire once?

Tags: jquery

For instance:

```
$('#btn1, #btn2').one('click', function(){
   // would fire once for btn1 click
   // and once more for btn2 click
})
```

If there is more than one element in the `$()` selector, the `one` function would fire more than once.

A simple way is to add a flag variable in the function to see whether it has been called. But it's not a graceful design because I may have another place to call the function.

So is there any way to make sure the function only fires once under one single `one` event-binding even if there are more than one elements in the $ selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`one()` attaches to every element in the collection, so the event can technically be raised multiple times; once per element.

To work around that you can call `off()` on all the elements to remove the event handler the first time it's invoked on *any* one of them. Also note that if you have multiple `click` event handlers bound and want to ensure you only remove this one, add a namespace to it. Try this:

```
let $els = $('#btn1, #btn2').on('click.mynamespace', function() {
  $els.off('click.mynamespace');
  // event handler...
});
```

Comment: But if there are other functions (event handlers) binding to the button, the `off` method would unbind them too. I want to only unbind the "one" handler function.

Comment: In which case you can add a custom namespace to the event. I've updated the answer to show you how